# How to add onfocus="this.select();" to an Inline edit table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this inline edit table using PHP and Mysqli. How can i select the content when i click inside a record to edit it using onfocus="this.select();"
The normal inline edit works fine, but the cursor is added next to the value on click or using tab. Please be so kind to assist

```
 <?php
          foreach($faq as $k=>$v) {
          ?>
              <tr class="table-row">
                <td><?php echo $k+1; ?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true"  onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'raceno','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);onfocus="this.select();"><?php echo $faq[$k]["raceno"]; ?> </td> </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

`onfocus` function is a self declared function and already exist as `event` for `input` elements.

You are setting that up as a variable in `onClick` function event

```
... onClick="showEdit(this);onfocus="this.select();">...
```

Instead, must be called as function:

```
... onClick="showEdit(this);" onfocus="this.select();">...
```